# How to filter the number of numberOfRowsInSection from plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to filter the number of rows from a plist file , but I don't know how to do that , I need to filter `events.count` to only 10 cells.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return events.count;

}
```

Comment: How do you want to filter? Just the 10 first one? Then, you could use another datasource array: `events10`, and put inside only the 10 firsts elements of `events`. Or you can return in this method 10.

Comment: @Larme Yes only 10 first one ... would you show me how to do it ?

Comment: `return 10;` instead of `return events.count;` should work. if tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is "correctly set".

Comment: @Larme app does crash ! because the plist downloads data from server

Comment: `if (events.count > 10) return 10; else return events.count;`? Anyway, if there is a crash you should give the error message, for better understanding, and where does it crash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the data from the server and when the data is loaded, you can call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Your number of items method shall be something like this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (events.count >= 10) {
        return 10;
    }
    else {
        return events.count;
    }
}
```

If you want to know why your app crashes, it's because you linked your table's data source and delegate to the view controller so it'll automatically call the data source protocol methods even if you didn't invoke reloadData, so if you always return 10, it'll call cellForRowAtIndexPath 10 times and you'll try to access the events array while it's still empty because the data hasn't been loaded from the server yet.

I guess the exception you are getting is index out of bound exception (index 0 is beyond array size)

The above shall solve your problem.